# How to get the add editing controls in a uitableviewcell to track touches

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to get the add (the green circle with the white plus) editing control to track touches.
The contacts program for example allows the user to touch either the cell itself or the circles on the left to carry out the add action.
Unfortunately, I don't get the same behaviour when I edit my tableViewCells. Only touches on the tableViewCell itself are tracked, touching the add green circle does nothing.

Is there any way to enable tracking of touches for these add editing controls.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you implement commitEditingStyle in your UITableViewController?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Add a new row to the data source     
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much, that was it.
I didn't implement this method as Apple's "Recipe" example code didn't.
I'll be more aware next time of completely trusting Apple's sample code.